# Uploading image Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:

Tags: php

I maked image upload for my form, but this going with adding time to error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'image' cannot be null' in /www/data08/users/i/itsiim.planet.ee/htdocs/progemine/system/lisa.php:58 Stack trace: #0 /www/data08/users/i/itsiim.planet.ee/htdocs/progemine/system/lisa.php(58): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /www/data08/users/i/itsiim.planet.ee/htdocs/progemine/system/lisa.php on line 58

```
<?php 
    require 'conf/db.php';
    if ( !empty($_POST)) {
        // keep track validation errors
        $nimiError = null;
        $emailError = null;
        $mobiilError = null;
        $suguError = null;

        // keep track post values
        $nimi = $_POST['nimi'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $mobiil = $_POST['mobiil'];
        $sugu = $_POST['sugu'];

        // validate input
        $valid = true;
        if (empty($nimi)) {
            $nimiError = 'Palun sisesta nimi';
            $valid = false;
        }

        if (empty($email)) {
            $emailError = 'Palun sisesta e-mail';
            $valid = false;
        } else if ( !filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
            $emailError = 'Palun sisesta korrektne e-mail';
            $valid = false;
        }

        if (empty($mobiil)) {
            $mobiilError = 'Palun sisesta mobiili number';
            $valid = false;
        }

        if (empty($sugu)) {
            $suguError = 'Palun vali sugu';
            $valid = false;
        }

        //Pilt
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){ 
            $folder = "upload/"; 
            $file = basename( $_FILES['image']['name']); 
            $full_path = $folder.$file; 
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $full_path)) { 
                $image = $full_path;
            }
        }


        // insert data
        if ($valid) {
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO kliendid (nimi,email,mobiil,sugu,image) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($nimi,$email,$mobiil,$sugu,$image));
            Database::disconnect();
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="et">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Klientide andmed by Siim Aarmaa IS-13</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="row">
                <h3>Lisa uus klient</h3>
            </div>

            <form class="form-horizontal" action="lisa.php" method="post">
              <div class="form-group <?php echo !empty($nimiError)?'error':'';?>">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nimi</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input name="nimi" type="text"  placeholder="Nimi" value="<?php echo !empty($nimi)?$nimi:'';?>">
                    <?php if (!empty($nimiError)): ?>
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $nimiError;?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group <?php echo !empty($emailError)?'error':'';?>">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">E-mail</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" value="<?php echo !empty($email)?$email:'';?>">
                    <?php if (!empty($emailError)): ?>
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $emailError;?></span>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group <?php echo !empty($mobiilError)?'error':'';?>">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Mobiili number</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input name="mobiil" type="text"  placeholder="Mobiili number" value="<?php echo !empty($mobiil)?$mobiil:'';?>">
                    <?php if (!empty($mobiilError)): ?>
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $mobiilError;?></span>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group <?php echo !empty($suguError)?'error':'';?>">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sugu</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input name="sugu" type="radio" value="<?php echo !empty($mees)?$mees:'Mees';?>">Mees
                    <input name="sugu" type="radio" value="<?php echo !empty($naine)?$naine:'Naine';?>">Naine
                    <?php if (!empty($suguError)): ?>
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $suguError;?></span>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </div><br>
                <div class="form-group <?php echo !empty($mobiilError)?'error':'';?>">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Pilt</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="file" name="image" required="required" value=""/>
                    <?php if (!empty($mobiilError)): ?>
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $mobiilError;?></span>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </div>
              </div>
                <br>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Lisa klient</button>
                  <a class="btn btn-default" href="index.php">Tagasi</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: does the image get uploaded ok and then moved to the correct directory?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something went wrong with the fileupload. You have no else branches for the is_uploaded_file() and move_uploaded_file() checks.

```
<?php 
require 'conf/db.php';
$errors = array();
if ( !isset($_POST['nimi'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['mobiil'],$_POST['sugu']) ) {
    $errors['parameter'] = 'missing POST parameter';
}
else {
    // keep track post values
    $nimi = $_POST['nimi'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mobiil = $_POST['mobiil'];
    $sugu = $_POST['sugu'];

    // validate input
    if (empty($nimi)) {
        $errors['nimi']  = 'Palun sisesta nimi';
    }

    if ( !filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
        $errors['email'] = 'Palun sisesta korrektne e-mail';
    }

    if (empty($mobiil)) {
        $errors['mobiil'] = 'Palun sisesta mobiili number';
    }

    if (empty($sugu)) {
        $errors['suguError'] = 'Palun vali sugu';
    }

    if ( empty($errors) ) {
        //Pilt
        if( !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) ) { 
            $errors['upload'] = 'no file uploaded';
        }
        else {
            $folder = "upload/"; 
            $file = basename( $_FILES['image']['name']); 
            $full_path = $folder.$file; 
            if( !move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $full_path) ) { 
                $errors['upload'] = 'cannot move file';
            }
            else {
                $image = $full_path;
            }
        }
    }
}

// insert data
if ( empty($errors) ) {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO kliendid (nimi,email,mobiil,sugu,image) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute( array($nimi,$email,$mobiil,$sugu,$image) );
    Database::disconnect();
    header("Location: index.php");
    die;
}
else {
    echo '<pre>', join("\r\n", $errors), '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the `Undefined index: image`, which means your file didn't get uploaded. And that's because you didn't set the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>` element. It should be,

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="lisa.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

    // your HTML code

</form>
```